# ResultSet .getString() very slow for large string against Azure SQL

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, azure-sql-database, mssql-jdbc

I'm using the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver to query data from an Azure SQL database. I am using ResultSet .getString to pull a large JSON string out of one of my table, and the performance of that method - for the same record - is all over the map. Anywhere from 1 second up to well over a minute or more.

The JSON I am fetching is around 10 - 15 Mb, so I suspect that has a lot to do with it. I'm just puzzled by the extreme swings in performance. Do you think this could be a Java heap space/GC issue maybe? Or could it have something to do with how the getString method actually works?

My actual query performance is consistently very good, under 1 second to get multiple rows of this big data base from the server.

Code snippet:

```
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
if (azureLogging) {
    System.out.println("Azure log: GetCustomerTariffs:" + new Date().toString() + " : query finished");
}
tariffs = new ArrayList<CustomerTariff>();

while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("Azure log: GetCustomerTariffs:" + new Date().toString() + " : getting JSON");

    jsonStr = rs.getString("tariff_json");
    System.out.println("Azure log: GetCustomerTariffs:" + new Date().toString() + " : got JSON");
    System.out.println(rs.getString("company_no") + ", " + rs.getString("scac"));
    System.out.println("Azure log: GetCustomerTariffs:" + new Date().toString() + " : deserializing JSON");
    CustomerTariff tariff =  respGson.fromJson(jsonStr, CustomerTariff.class);
    System.out.println("Azure log: GetCustomerTariffs:" + new Date().toString() + " : JSON deserialized");

    tariffs.add(tariff);
}
```

Comment: People may need more information to help you: such as which JDBC driver you're using; the query you run; your table/index definitions. Also, how did you measure to determine what's taking the most time and is it a specific getString() or all of the getString() calls?

Comment: <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.1.jre8</version>

Comment: Hi @Rick Bonnett, I've updated my answer. Kindly let me know if you need more information.  : )

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Parameter Sniffing may cause slow query, follow this [article](https://www.sqlshack.com/query-optimization-techniques-in-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/), we can find and resolve Parameter Sniffing.

---

1. I think you should first use [Query Performance Insight for Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/query-performance-insight-use) to see the top resource consuming and long-running queries in your workload. You can [dynamically scale database resources with minimal downtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/scale-resources).
2. We also can use connection pool in our jdbc app to mitigate the cost of opening new connections and manage resources efficiently. [Improve JDBC application reliability with Azure SQL and connection pooling](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/improve-jdbc-application-reliability-with-azure-sql-and-connection-pooling/).

Comment: Thank you Joseph. I'm not seeing an issue with query performance per se - that seems quite good. Where my problem lies is the ResultSet.getString() call to fetch my large JSON strings after my query execution has completed